# command line tool to change audio's noise gate

Tags: audio

does anyone know a command line based tool that can change the noise gate of an audio file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [SoX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoX). It's a bundle of command line tools for audio processing. Features various audio filters, among them some for noise reduction.